# Restart remote server IIS App Pool. The RPC server is unavailable

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, iis-7.5, rpc

I have a service that tries to restart an app pool on a different server in the same domain.  The service is running under the domain admin account.  The IIS is v.7.5 Windows 2008 R2 box. .NET 4.0.  We are impersonating as this admin account.

Any idea why this error is being thrown?  Active Directory?  The account does not have IIS permissions?

Thanks in advance.

From the service trace log:

```
GetWebServer: Current Username [before impersonation]: 'MYDOMAIN\domain_admin_account'
GetWebServer: Current Username [during impersonation]: 'MYDOMAIN\domain_admin_account'
GetIISWebServer: Current Username: 'MYDOMAIN\domain_admin_account'
LoadMetaBase: Current Username: 'MYDOMAIN\domain_admin_account'
LoadMetaBase: serverDirectoryEntryPath: 'IIS://SERVERNAME/W3SVC'
The RPC server is unavailable.

The RPC server is unavailable.

GetWebServer: Current Username [after impersonation]: 'MYDOMAIN\domain_admin_account'
The RPC server is unavailable.

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800706BA): The RPC server is unavailable.

   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Exists(String path)
   at SomeNamespace.IISManagement.IISWebServer.LoadMetaBase()
   at SomeNamespace.IISManagement.IISWebServer..ctor(String serverName)
   at SomeNamespace.IISManagement.IISWebServer.GetIISWebServer(String serverName)
   at SomeNamespace.IISManagement.IISManager.GetWebServer(String serverName)
   at SomeNamespace.IISManagement.IISManager.RestartApplicationPool(String serverName, String applicationPoolName)
   at SomeNamespace.Common.ServiceFunctions.IISAppPoolAction(String serverName, String appPoolName, String action)
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the WMI provider installed on the remote machine?  See this [link](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/162/managing-sites-with-iis39s-wmi-provider/) for more information.

Comment: No, we don't have it installed.  The remote server is an exact copy of another web server we have, except that the new server is in the same domain as the server the service (that requests the app pool restart) is running on.  Service on Domain1, Old Web server on Domain 2.  New Web server on Domain1.  That is the only difference.  New and old Web servers are identical in every way, down to the IIS settings and services.  Service is able to restart App pools on old Web server, but not the new one.  Thanks.

Comment: Could we have missed some settings or permissions on the new Web server?

Comment: @user1100221 If this is an exact copy of the old server, I doubt that you would miss the permissions.

Comment: I just found out there is a firewall between Service on Domain1 and the New Web Server on Domain1, which is why the RPC call would be failing.  Would you know what RPC ports we should have our firewall team open?  Thanks!

Comment: @user1100221 Use a ethereal on the server that requests the restart.  This will show you what port it is trying to communicate on.

Comment: Thanks Josh.  We are trying to do that now.